# DMCloud API to DM Partner API mapping ( PHP SDK )

Tags: dailymotion-api

I am in process of migrating from DMCloud to DM Partner Program and was wondering if there was an equivalent for,

- get_embed_url()
- get_stream_url()

[Link to dmcloud documentation](https://www.dmcloud.net/doc/api/sdk-php.html#media-object)

**Goal:**
To be able to receive embed urls from DM for private videos. It seems DM's player API returns iframe and link is not signed / perishable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With Dailymotion API, you can query the following fields on the video object:

- [`embed_url`](https://developer.dailymotion.com/documentation#video-embed_url-field) which is the url to embed the video. If your video is private, this query returns an url to embed the video with an id beginning by "k", it is the private id of the video. If you share it (embed the video on a public web page), the video is no longer "private" (any user checking the code will be able to access the embed url).
- [`stream_source_url`](https://developer.dailymotion.com/documentation#video-stream_source_url-field) and all others `stream_*_url` fields. It refers to the URL of this video source. This field has some protections:

  - only the owner of the video can retrieve it, (s)he has to pass a valid access token otherwise this field returns null
  - the url can only be consumed by the user who made the api call
  - the url returned is valid for 2 days
  - this field is rate limited

Comment: Thanks. I just to need to embed my private videos (from DM) onto my website, which should be accessible by the website user and preferably the embed url should expire in 2hrs (like in dmcloud). What approach do you suggest?

Comment: unfortunately, this feature is not available on dailymotion.com